# Bugs in android app using openCV and JNI on my Nexus 4

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a problem with my AR app using OpenCV for drivers. I build native app using JNI(c++) and OpenCV. Everything works fine, but sometimes, after some 60-70 s my app crashes. I am new on Android and I don't know, what to do, because my logs nothing tell me. I use NativeCameraView and onProcessFrame() method which refers to native methods. I noticed that the same thing is happening with all OpenCV samples that it uses a native code and onProcessFrame() method. My nexus turns off with characteristic sound! I think that this is the sound of the camera :(  I haven't other devices on android :( I don't know what to do and what think, It is my fault(code), my device or OpenCV library? Sorry for my English ;) Here is my error logs below, before device disconnected:

```
> 01-08 18:45:43.390: E/OpenCV::camera(2870):
> ||libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so 01-08 18:45:43.390:
> E/OpenCV::camera(2870): ||libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so 01-08
> 18:45:43.390: E/OpenCV::camera(2870): ||libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so
> 01-08 18:45:43.390: E/OpenCV::camera(2870):
> ||libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so 01-08 18:45:43.390:
> E/OpenCV::camera(2870): ||libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so 01-08
> 18:45:43.390: E/OpenCV::camera(2870): ||libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
> 01-08 18:45:43.390: E/OpenCV::camera(2870):
> ||libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so 01-08 18:45:43.390:
> E/OpenCV::camera(2870): ||libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so 01-08
> 18:45:43.390: E/OpenCV::camera(2870): ||libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
> 01-08 18:45:44.051: E/OpenCV::camera(2870): calling
> (*pGetPropertyC)(0x74fedfa0, 2) 01-08 18:45:44.141:
> E/OpenCV::camera(2870): calling (*pGetPropertyC)(0x74fedfa0, 0) 01-08
> 18:45:44.141: E/OpenCV::camera(2870): calling
> (*pGetPropertyC)(0x74fedfa0, 1) 01-08 18:45:44.421:
> E/OpenCV_for_Tegra(2870): Canot create OpenGL context 01-08
> 18:45:44.431: E/OpenCV::camera(2870): calling
> (*pGetPropertyC)(0x74fedfa0, 3) 01-08 18:45:52.440:
> E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870): CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048
> ext1=0 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:52.500: E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870):
> CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048 ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:52.560:
> E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870): CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048
> ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:52.620: E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870):
> CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048 ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:52.680:
> E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870): CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048
> ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:52.740: E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870):
> CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048 ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:52.800:
> E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870): CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048
> ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:52.860: E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870):
> CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048 ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:52.920:
> E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870): CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048
> ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:52.980: E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870):
> CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048 ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:53.040:
> E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870): CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048
> ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:53.100: E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870):
> CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048 ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:53.160:
> E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870): CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048
> ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:53.220: E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870):
> CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048 ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:53.280:
> E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870): CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048
> ext1=1 ext2=0 01-08 18:45:53.341: E/OpenCV_NativeCamera(2870):
> CameraHandler::Notify: msgType=2048 ext1=0 ext2=0
```

Logs after device disconnected:

```
> 01-08 18:42:01.504: E/Sensors(292): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa: fflush
> failed, 9 01-08 18:42:01.504: E/Sensors(292): sns_fsa_la.c(386):fsa:
> fflush failed, 9 01-08 18:42:01.644: E/mm-camera(294): qcamsvr_start:
> old_mode = 3f 01-08 18:42:01.644: E/WifiUtil(295): Change
> Intf0MacAddress=C4438FCB0DA8 01-08 18:42:01.764: E/mm-camera(294):
> qcamsvr_load_gesture_lib Error opening gesture library 01-08
> 18:42:01.764: E/mm-camera(294): Cannot init Gesture library 01-08
> 18:42:01.834: E/(178): [ACDB RTC]->rtc init done!->result [0] 01-08
> 18:42:01.834: E/Diag_Lib(178):  Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle
> to diag driver, error = 13 01-08 18:42:01.834: E/Diag_Lib(178):
> actp_diag_init: diag init failed 01-08 18:42:01.834: E/(178): [ACDB
> ACPH]->actp diag init done! 01-08 18:42:01.864: E/(178):
> csd_client_service_init: Invalid rx device 0, setting to handset 01-08
> 18:42:01.864: E/(178): csd_client_service_init: Invalid tx device 0,
> setting to handset 01-08 18:42:01.864: E/QMI_FW(178): xport_open:
> socket creation failed - 1 01-08 18:42:01.864: E/Diag_Lib(178): 
> Diag_LSM_Init: Failed to open handle to diag driver, error = 13 01-08
> 18:42:02.755: E/Sensors(292): sns_debug_main.c(565):Debug Config File
> missing in EFS! 01-08 18:42:03.365: E/kickstart-qcks(171):
> RUNNING:  /system/bin/ks  -w /data/tombstones/mdm/ -p
> /dev/ks_hsic_bridge -r 21 -s 2:/firmware/image/amss.mbn -s
> 6:/firmware/image/apps.mbn -s 8:/firmware/image/dsp1.mbn -s
> 11:/firmware/image/osbl.mbn -s 12:/firmware/image/dsp2.mbn -s
> 21:/firmware/image/sbl1.mbn -s 22:/firmware/image/sbl2.mbn -s
> 23:/firmware/image/rpm.mbn -s 28:/firmware/image/dsp3.mbn -s
> 16:/data/qcks/efs1.bin -s 17:/data/qcks/efs2.bin -s
> 20:/data/qcks/efs3.bin -s 29:/data/qcks/acdb.bin 01-08 18:42:03.386:
> E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:03.386:
> E/kickstart(598): Requested ID 21, file "/firmware/image/sbl1.mbn"
> 01-08 18:42:03.516: E/kickstart(598): 117700 bytes transferred in
> 0.128s (0.88 MBps) 01-08 18:42:03.516: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:42:03.746: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:03.756: E/kickstart(598): Received
> file "/data/tombstones/mdm/load.cmm" 01-08 18:42:03.756:
> E/kickstart(598): 752 bytes transferred in 0.001s (0.94 MBps) 01-08
> 18:42:03.766: E/kickstart(598): Received file
> "/data/tombstones/mdm/RST_STAT.BIN" 01-08 18:42:03.766:
> E/kickstart(598): 4 bytes transferred in 0.005s (0.00 MBps) 01-08
> 18:42:03.766: E/kickstart(598): Received file
> "/data/tombstones/mdm/RPM_REG.BIN" 01-08 18:42:03.766:
> E/kickstart(598): 228 bytes transferred in 0.002s (0.12 MBps) 01-08
> 18:42:03.766: E/kickstart(598): Received file
> "/data/tombstones/mdm/CPU_REG.BIN" 01-08 18:42:03.766:
> E/kickstart(598): 172 bytes transferred in 0.004s (0.05 MBps) 01-08
> 18:42:03.776: E/kickstart(598): Received file
> "/data/tombstones/mdm/LPASS.BIN" 01-08 18:42:03.776: E/kickstart(598):
> 16384 bytes transferred in 0.004s (4.20 MBps) 01-08 18:42:03.776:
> E/kickstart(598): Received file "/data/tombstones/mdm/RPM_MSG.BIN"
> 01-08 18:42:03.776: E/kickstart(598): 24576 bytes transferred in
> 0.004s (6.51 MBps) 01-08 18:42:03.856: E/EmojiFactory_jni(176): Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
> 01-08 18:42:10.954: E/kickstart(598): Received file
> "/data/tombstones/mdm/EBI1.BIN" 01-08 18:42:10.954: E/kickstart(598):
> 134217728 bytes transferred in 7.158s (17.88 MBps) 01-08 18:42:10.964:
> E/kickstart(598): Received file "/data/tombstones/mdm/CODERAM.BIN"
> 01-08 18:42:10.964: E/kickstart(598): 147456 bytes transferred in
> 0.009s (15.31 MBps) 01-08 18:42:10.964: E/kickstart(598): Received file "/data/tombstones/mdm/SYS_IMEM.BIN" 01-08 18:42:10.964:
> E/kickstart(598): 16384 bytes transferred in 0.002s (6.48 MBps) 01-08
> 18:42:10.984: E/kickstart(598): Received file
> "/data/tombstones/mdm/Q6_TCM.BIN" 01-08 18:42:10.984:
> E/kickstart(598): 262144 bytes transferred in 0.021s (11.96 MBps)
> 01-08 18:42:10.984: E/kickstart(598): Successfully downloaded files
> from target  01-08 18:42:10.984: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:42:10.984: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:10.994: E/kickstart(598): Requested
> ID 23, file "/firmware/image/rpm.mbn" 01-08 18:42:11.144:
> E/kickstart(598): 105696 bytes transferred in 0.148s (0.68 MBps) 01-08
> 18:42:11.144: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08
> 18:42:11.144: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08
> 18:42:11.144: E/kickstart(598): Requested ID 22, file
> "/firmware/image/sbl2.mbn" 01-08 18:42:11.264: E/kickstart(598):
> 242376 bytes transferred in 0.120s (1.93 MBps) 01-08 18:42:11.264:
> E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:42:11.274:
> E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:11.284:
> E/kickstart(598): Requested ID 12, file "/firmware/image/dsp2.mbn"
> 01-08 18:42:14.768: E/kickstart(598): 32145486 bytes transferred in
> 3.480s (8.81 MBps) 01-08 18:42:14.768: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:42:14.778: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:14.788: E/kickstart(598): Requested
> ID 28, file "/firmware/image/dsp3.mbn" 01-08 18:42:15.338:
> E/kickstart(598): 6334186 bytes transferred in 0.556s (10.87 MBps)
> 01-08 18:42:15.338: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock
> 01-08 18:42:15.338: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock
> 01-08 18:42:15.348: E/kickstart(598): Requested ID 8, file
> "/firmware/image/dsp1.mbn" 01-08 18:42:15.609: E/kickstart(598):
> 2688527 bytes transferred in 0.268s (9.57 MBps) 01-08 18:42:15.609:
> E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:42:15.609:
> E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:15.619:
> E/kickstart(598): Requested ID 16, file "/data/qcks/efs1.bin" 01-08
> 18:42:15.679: E/kickstart(598): 786472 bytes transferred in 0.064s
> (11.72 MBps) 01-08 18:42:15.679: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:42:15.679: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:15.689: E/kickstart(598): Requested
> ID 17, file "/data/qcks/efs2.bin" 01-08 18:42:15.749:
> E/kickstart(598): 786472 bytes transferred in 0.060s (12.51 MBps)
> 01-08 18:42:15.749: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock
> 01-08 18:42:15.749: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock
> 01-08 18:42:15.749: E/kickstart(598): Requested ID 20, file
> "/data/qcks/efs3.bin" 01-08 18:42:15.809: E/kickstart(598): 786472
> bytes transferred in 0.064s (11.73 MBps) 01-08 18:42:15.809:
> E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:42:15.809:
> E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:15.819:
> E/kickstart(598): Requested ID 29, file "/data/qcks/acdb.bin" 01-08
> 18:42:15.969: E/kickstart(598): 2097192 bytes transferred in 0.152s
> (13.16 MBps) 01-08 18:42:15.969: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:42:15.969: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:15.969: E/kickstart(598): Requested
> ID 6, file "/firmware/image/apps.mbn" 01-08 18:42:16.309:
> E/kickstart(598): 2630368 bytes transferred in 0.336s (7.47 MBps)
> 01-08 18:42:16.309: E/kickstart(598): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_unlock
> 01-08 18:42:16.309: E/kickstart(598): Sahara protocol completed 01-08
> 18:42:16.309: E/kickstart(598): Removing linked list of input files
> 01-08 18:42:16.309: E/kickstart(598): Removing linked list of input
> files 01-08 18:42:16.309: E/kickstart-qcks(171): Sahara transfer
> completed successfully 01-08 18:42:16.309: E/kickstart-qcks(171):
> Spawning efsks 01-08 18:42:16.319: E/kickstart-efsks(629): File
> '/dev/efs_hsic_bridge' was not found 01-08 18:42:16.319:
> E/kickstart-efsks(629): /dev/efs_hsic_bridge does not exist. 01-08
> 18:42:18.321: E/kickstart-efsks(629): RUNNING: '/system/bin/ks -m -w
> /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/ -p /dev/efs_hsic_bridge -t -1
> -l' 01-08 18:42:18.331: E/kickstart(634): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:42:18.331: E/kickstart(634): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:42:19.222: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD:
> Service_id=23 not found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.222:
> E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD: Service_id=24 not found over conn_id=0 01-08
> 18:42:19.222: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD: Service_id=24 not found over
> conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.232: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD: Service_id=23 not
> found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.242: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD:
> Service_id=24 not found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.242:
> E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD: Service_id=24 not found over conn_id=0 01-08
> 18:42:19.252: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD: Service_id=23 not found over
> conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.262: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD: Service_id=24 not
> found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.272: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD:
> Service_id=24 not found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.302:
> E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD: Service_id=23 not found over conn_id=0 01-08
> 18:42:19.313: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD: Service_id=24 not found over
> conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.323: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD: Service_id=23 not
> found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.333: E/QMI_FW(185): QMUXD:
> Service_id=24 not found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.873:
> E/QMI_FW(178): QMUXD: Service_id=20 not found over conn_id=0 01-08
> 18:42:19.893: E/QMI_FW(178): QMUXD: Service_id=20 not found over
> conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.913: E/QMI_FW(178): QMUXD: Service_id=20 not
> found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.933: E/QMI_FW(178): QMUXD:
> Service_id=20 not found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:19.943:
> E/QMI_FW(178): QMUXD: Service_id=20 not found over conn_id=0 01-08
> 18:42:20.033: E/MonoPipe(178): Failed to fetch local time frequency
> when constructing a MonoPipe (res = -32).  getNextWriteTimestamp calls
> will be non-functional 01-08 18:42:23.827: E/ConsumerIrService(604):
> Can't open consumer IR HW Module, error: -2 01-08 18:42:23.827:
> E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK(186): Failed to reset optimization for resource: 4
> level: 0 01-08 18:42:24.358: E/ConnectivityService(604): Ignoring
> protectedNetwork 14 01-08 18:42:24.378: E/MobileDataStateTracker(604):
> default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire
> PhoneService 01-08 18:42:24.378: E/MobileDataStateTracker(604):
> default: Could not enable APN type "default" 01-08 18:42:24.918:
> E/OMXMaster(178): A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac'
> already exists, ignoring this one. 01-08 18:42:25.789:
> E/LocSvc_utils_cfg(604): W/loc_read_conf: no /etc/sap.conf file found
> 01-08 18:42:25.789: E/LocSvc_afw(604): W/get_extension: Invalid
> interface passed in 01-08 18:42:25.849: E/QMI_FW(604): xport_open:
> socket creation failed - 1 01-08 18:42:25.849: E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD:
> Service_id=16 not found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:25.849:
> E/LocationManagerService(604): No FusedProvider found. 01-08
> 18:42:25.869: E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD: Service_id=16 not found over
> conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:25.880: E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD: Service_id=16 not
> found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:25.910: E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD:
> Service_id=16 not found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:25.930:
> E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD: Service_id=16 not found over conn_id=0 01-08
> 18:42:25.960: E/QMI_FW(604): xport_open: socket creation failed - 1
> 01-08 18:42:25.960: E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD: Service_id=16 not found over
> conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:25.980: E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD: Service_id=16 not
> found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:25.990: E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD:
> Service_id=16 not found over conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:26.030:
> E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD: Service_id=16 not found over conn_id=0 01-08
> 18:42:26.040: E/QMI_FW(604): QMUXD: Service_id=16 not found over
> conn_id=0 01-08 18:42:26.270: E/NfcAdaptation(857):
> NfcAdaptation::Initialize: ver=NFCDROID_MI_422.10.0.15
> nfa=NFA_MI_1.03.62+ 01-08 18:42:26.280: E/NfcNciHal(857):
> HaiInitializeLibrary: ver=NFCDROID_MI_422.10.0.15 nfa=NFA_MI_1.03.62+
> 01-08 18:42:26.310: E/KeepSync(825): Try to add invalid account 01-08
> 18:42:26.310: E/KeepSync(825): Try to force sync on a null account
> 01-08 18:42:26.310: E/KeepSync(825): Try to add invalid account 01-08
> 18:42:26.310: E/KeepSync(825): Try to force sync on a null account
> 01-08 18:42:26.821: E/NfcNciHal(857): NVM patch version is 147.157
> 01-08 18:42:26.821: E/BluetoothPhoneService(844): Could not get a
> handle on Connection object for the call 01-08 18:42:29.323:
> E/WifiStateMachine(604): Unexpected BatchedScanResults :OK 01-08
> 18:42:29.694: E/WiredAccessoryManager(604): No state change. 01-08
> 18:42:30.635: E/bt-btm(1167): BTM_SecRegister:p_cb_info->p_le_callback
> == 0x74e8e811  01-08 18:42:30.635: E/bt-btm(1167): BTM_SecRegister: btm_cb.api.p_le_callback = 0x74e8e811  01-08 18:42:30.645:
> E/bt-btif(1167): Calling BTA_HhEnable 01-08 18:42:30.645:
> E/bt-btif(1167): btif_storage_get_adapter_property
> service_mask:0x140040 01-08 18:42:30.655: E/bt_mct(1167): hci lib
> postload completed 01-08 18:42:30.685: E/BluetoothServiceJni(1167):
> SOCK FLAG = 1 *********************** 01-08 18:42:31.055:
> E/UpdateRequestReceiver(1268): ignoring update request 01-08
> 18:42:31.055: E/UpdateRequestReceiver(1268): ignoring update request
> 01-08 18:42:31.065: E/UpdateRequestReceiver(1268): ignoring update
> request 01-08 18:42:31.075: E/UpdateRequestReceiver(1268): ignoring
> update request 01-08 18:42:31.075: E/UpdateRequestReceiver(1268):
> ignoring update request 01-08 18:42:31.085:
> E/UpdateRequestReceiver(1268): ignoring update request 01-08
> 18:42:35.600: E/ConnectivityService(604): Unexpected mtu value:
> android.net.wifi.WifiStateTracker@428b90a0 01-08 18:42:38.794:
> E/LocSvc_eng(604): W/int loc_eng_inject_time(loc_eng_data_s_type&,
> GpsUtcTime, int64_t, int): log_eng state error: instance not
> initialized 01-08 18:42:44.479: E/KeepSync(1622): Try to add invalid
> account 01-08 18:42:44.479: E/KeepSync(1622): Try to force sync on a
> null account 01-08 18:42:44.479: E/KeepSync(1622): Try to add invalid
> account 01-08 18:42:44.479: E/KeepSync(1622): Try to force sync on a
> null account 01-08 18:42:45.340: E/LocSvc_eng(604): W/int
> loc_eng_inject_location(loc_eng_data_s_type&, double, double, float):
> log_eng state error: instance not initialized 01-08 18:42:46.801:
> E/LocSvc_eng(604): W/int loc_eng_inject_location(loc_eng_data_s_type&,
> double, double, float): log_eng state error: instance not initialized
> 01-08 18:42:48.343: E/skype_jni(1900): g_jniCallback == 0 01-08
> 18:42:48.343: E/skype_jni(1900): g_pcmInit == 0 01-08 18:42:48.613:
> E/dalvikvm(1900): Could not find class
> 'com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM', referenced from method
> com.skype.android.push.adm.ADMPushRegistration.isSupported 01-08
> 18:42:56.812: E/Finsky(2079): [185]
> RecommendedWidgetProvider.getWidgetWithTitle: No browse URL found for
> backend=0 01-08 18:42:56.862: E/Finsky(2079): [185]
> RecommendedWidgetProvider.getWidgetWithTitle: No browse URL found for
> backend=0 01-08 18:42:57.173: E/dalvikvm(2131): Could not find class
> 'com.google.trix.ritz.shared.messages.b', referenced from method
> bih.<init> 01-08 18:42:57.183: E/dalvikvm(2131): Could not find class
> 'com.google.trix.ritz.shared.render.g', referenced from method
> bih.<init> 01-08 18:42:57.183: E/dalvikvm(2131): Could not find class
> 'com.google.trix.ritz.shared.behavior.validation.a', referenced from
> method bih.<init> 01-08 18:42:57.183: E/dalvikvm(2131): Could not find
> class 'com.google.trix.ritz.shared.mutation.N', referenced from method
> bih.<init> 01-08 18:43:00.526: E/ANDR-PERF-LOCK(186): Failed to apply
> optimization for resource: 4 level: 0 01-08 18:43:01.898:
> E/BluetoothServiceJni(1167): SOCK FLAG = 1 ***********************
> 01-08 18:43:01.938: E/BluetoothServiceJni(1167): SOCK FLAG = 0
> *********************** 01-08 18:43:03.009: E/PhoneMonitor(2302): onOtaspChanged old =0, new =3 01-08 18:43:07.764: E/LocSvc_eng(604):
> W/int loc_eng_inject_location(loc_eng_data_s_type&, double, double,
> float): log_eng state error: instance not initialized 01-08
> 18:44:28.680: E/LocSvc_eng(604): W/int
> loc_eng_inject_location(loc_eng_data_s_type&, double, double, float):
> log_eng state error: instance not initialized 01-08 18:44:29.211:
> E/kickstart(634): Wrote to /sys/power/wake_lock 01-08 18:44:29.401:
> E/kickstart(634): Received file
> "/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/m9kefs1" 01-08 18:44:29.401:
> E/kickstart(634): 786432 bytes transferred in 0.182s (4.12 MBps) 01-08
> 18:44:29.401: E/kickstart(634): Successfully downloaded files from
> target  01-08 18:44:29.401: E/kickstart(634): Wrote to
> /sys/power/wake_unlock 01-08 18:44:29.401: E/kickstart(634): Sahara
> protocol completed
```

Answer (score 0):

There are known defects with NativeCameraView for some devices

see [Release notes Android OpenCV](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Android_Release_Notes#OpenCV-for-Android-Release-Notes)

The workaround is to use the JavaCameraView instead of the Native